# CentOS 7 'No matching Packages to list' for man

Tags: centos, yum

As part of my test environment I'm running CentOS 6.6 in one VM and CentOS 7 in another. They are both relatively fresh installs, running Puppet.

However, when I run `yum list man` on the CentOS 7 box it searches the repositories and returns 'No matching Packages to list.'

When I run the same command on CentOS 6.6, it finds the `man.x86_64` package.

Checked `yum repolist` and both have the CentOS Base, EPEL, extras, and updates repositories installed.

They are both minimal installations of CentOS.

This seems to indicate to me that the `man.x86_64` package is not in the Centos7 base repository. Is this correct or an error in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum whatprovides man
```

on my CentOS 7 machine shows the package is `man-db`

Comment: ...and verified. The naming must have indeed changed. Thank youuuu :)